# Extra fee for cross shard transactions

Tags: transactions, gas, sharding, cross-shard-transaction

I have been looking into sharding and I wanted to figure out how much extra fee or gas does a person needs to spend on a cross shard transaction compared to a transaction within a shard.

What could be the relationship between the two gas prices and how are they calculated?

Comment: Some coding example might be useful here.

Comment: It is a theoretical question.